# Plotting mean and +/- sigma on a time vs variable graph

Tags: r, statistics, visualization

I am trying to create an historical visualization of data showing mean and +/- 1 sigma lines on a month-by-month basis. Currently, I have created a summarized table from the data, then added manually each mean and + sigma (for the sake of the example only) by using geom_segment. This is not very lean. I tried geom_smooth or similar functions but I don't know how to group the data and display the reference lines accordingly.

Many thanks in advance!

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dates <- as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-08", "2021-01-12", "2021-01-17", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-26", "2021-01-29", "2021-02-01", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-04", "2021-02-08", "2021-02-12", "2021-02-17", "2021-02-21", "2021-02-26", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-02", "2021-03-04", "2021-03-08", "2021-03-12", "2021-03-17", "2021-03-21", "2021-03-26", "2021-03-29"))
all_values <- c(sample(15:25, 9, replace=FALSE), sample(18:27, 9, replace=FALSE), sample(10:25, 9, replace=FALSE))


full_table <- tibble(dates,all_values)

summary_values <- full_table %>% 
  mutate(Month_Category = format(dates, "%Y-%m" )) %>% 
  group_by(Month_Category) %>% 
  summarise(mean_values = mean(all_values), sd_top = mean(all_values) + sd(all_values), sd_bot = mean(all_values)- sd (all_values)) %>% 
  ungroup()
  

History_graph <- full_table %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = all_values)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "History", x = "Date", y = "values") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size = 12), axis.title = element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12), axis.title = element_text(size=12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(5, 30, by=5), limits=c(5, 30)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '3 days', labels=date_format('%d-%b'), expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2021-01-01"), xend=as.Date("2021-01-31"), y=summary_values$mean_values[1], yend = summary_values$mean_values[1])) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2021-02-01"), xend=as.Date("2021-02-28"), y=summary_values$mean_values[2], yend = summary_values$mean_values[2])) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2021-03-01"), xend=as.Date("2021-03-31"), y=summary_values$mean_values[3], yend = summary_values$mean_values[3])) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2021-01-01"), xend=as.Date("2021-01-31"), y=summary_values$sd_top[1], yend = summary_values$sd_top[1])) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2021-02-01"), xend=as.Date("2021-02-28"), y=summary_values$sd_top[2], yend = summary_values$sd_top[2])) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2021-03-01"), xend=as.Date("2021-03-31"), y=summary_values$sd_top[3], yend = summary_values$sd_top[3])) 

History_graph
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this problem.
One alternative is to create mean and +/- 1 sd values with mutate, then simply add geom_line for the different values and group by Category. Much simpler than previous approach.

Kind Regards

```
full_table <- tibble(dates,all_values) %>% 
  mutate(Month_Category = format(dates, "%Y-%m" )) %>% 
  group_by(Month_Category) %>% 
  mutate(mean_values = mean(all_values)) %>% 
  mutate(sd_top = mean(all_values) + sd(all_values)) %>% 
  mutate(sd_bot = mean(all_values)- sd (all_values)) %>% 
  ungroup()

History_graph <- full_table %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = all_values)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "History", x = "Date", y = "values") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size = 12), axis.title = element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12), axis.title = element_text(size=12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(5, 30, by=5), limits=c(5, 30)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '3 days', labels=date_format('%d-%b'), expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_values, group = Month_Category), color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = sd_top, group = Month_Category), color = "gray") +
  geom_line(aes(y = sd_bot, group = Month_Category), color = "gray") 

History_graph
```